# How to create an irregular triangle grid in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

How might I create an irregular trianglular grid like this one?   It would be nice to be able to distort the pentagons/hexagons rather than drawing the grid using the pen tool.

Thanks..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to manually create this.

Or create a standard triangle grid and use the `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` to distort things after the standard grid is created.